# Error when console compiling Clion project

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, sfml, clion

I created an SFML project in Clion. Below I have provided CmakeLists. When I build and compile the project with Clion, it compiles successfully. But if I try to build a CMake project without CLion, but using the console, and then compile it, then a compilation error occurs, which I have attached below. Question: why does the error occur exactly when building and compiling outside of Clion? And how to fix it?

Main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(arcade_games)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics window system audio REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(window)
```

executable CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(window WIN32 src/window.cpp)

target_link_libraries(window PRIVATE sfml-system sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-main)

target_include_directories(window PRIVATE include)
```

Error:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable window.exe
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/projects/testSFML/sfml/MinGW/lib/libsfml-system-s-d.a(Err.cpp.obj):Err.cpp:(.rdata+0x40): undefined reference to `std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::seekpos(std::fpos<int>, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [window\CMakeFiles\window.dir\build.make:105: window/window.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:97: window/CMakeFiles/window.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:90: all] Error 2
```

CMake flags:

```
-G "MinGW Makefiles" cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=sfml/MinGW/lib/cmake/SFML
```

If I try to compile a project that, for example, still uses sfml-audio with all the libraries necessary for it, then the same error occurs, only with FLAC, Vorbis, etc.

Comment: You missed `-static-libstdc++`

Comment: I did. The command is now: `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")`. But for some reason the error is the same.

Comment: Try the lower C++ standard `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`, same as one used in sfml, otherwise you have to build it from the sources

Comment: It still doesn't work! If I remove these flags: `set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)` `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++")`, then everything seems to be compiled, but it is compiled dynamically, which I would not like